# What is the proper phrase for being in one's official limits, probably when quoting something?

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions, phrase-requests

While quoting something, the consideration of the fact that it does not offend the sentiments of a community or culture one belongs to. How do we ask that in one sentence e.g Did I remain in my limits/Did I not overdo my limits?

Comment: There are many phrases one could use there, so there is no single "proper" phrase.

Answer (score 3):

You've actually got two different questions in there.

To remain within your limits is as @mplungian says

> *overstep one's bounds*

For example, *I hope I didn't **overstep my bounds** when I told you to be quiet*.

Second, to stop and consider whether something will offend a particular culture or community before saying it is to be:

> [*politically correct*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness) : seeking to minimize social and institutional offense in occupational, gender, racial, cultural, sexual orientation, certain other religions, [etc]

Answer (score 1):

A good idiom is *overstepping my boundaries* (or bounds)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to address your position more specifically, you can use, ***" . . . did I exceed the scope of my authority?"***

or

***" . . . did I exceed the boundaries of my office?"***

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question title and content provide two different context.

In the context of the question's title, the *proper* word to use would be **jurisdiction**.

[Jurisdiction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jurisdiction): (3)  *the limits or territory within which authority may be exercised*

So that would be the term to use for "*official territory*".

However, according to the context provided by you in the content I would suggest you use "*I hope I didn't offend (you/your sensibilities)*" or "*I hope i didn't overstep myself*".